# Twilio.Device.setup without permission to access user's microphone?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm using Twilio to connect a browser client to a conference call. Some of these users are in corporate environments where access to microphone is blocked.

Is there a way to setup Twilio.Device to just listen in on the conference call, without requiring access to the microphone?

I tried the following, but doesn't seem to help:

```
var audioConstraints = { optional: [{ audio: false }] };
Twilio.Device.setup(token, audioConstraints);
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When setting [parameters on your `Twilio.Device`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#setup) the ones that are passed through to `getUserMedia` are passed as `audioConstraints`. The following code should stop requiring mic access:

```
var params = { audioConstraints: { audio: false } };
Twilio.Device.setup(token, params);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.